# Android: Hidden part of view doesn't show after drag it up

Tags: android, viewdraghelper

I'm trying to use **ViewDragHelp** to implement draggable panel but the problem is the hidden part of panel isn't shown. [Picture what i meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHRxR.png)

Here is my code . SlidePanel is the draggable panel and the "white_pane" is the partially hidden panel (i set the bttom margin as -280dp)

SlidePanel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    >

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/name_pane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/name_layout"
         >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/white_pane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-200dp"
    android:background="#F0F2F4">
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

SlidePanel.java

```
public class SlidePanel extends LinearLayout {
private ViewDragHelper mDragHelper;
protected ViewGroup whitePanel;
protected ViewGroup namePanel;
protected TextView nameText;
private Status status;
private Animation show , hide;
MapsActivity mapAct;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

private int mDraggingBorder;
private int mVerticalRange;
private boolean mIsOpen;
private final double AUTO_OPEN_SPEED_LIMIT = 800.0;
private int mDraggingState = 0;

public SlidePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();

}
public SlidePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();
}
public SlidePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();
}
public void init()
{
    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_panel, this, true);
    //hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)mapAct.findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
    whitePanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.white_pane);
    namePanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.name_pane);
    nameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_text);
    //slidingLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout)mapAct.findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
    status = Status.HIDDEN;
    this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(this,1.0f , new DragHelperCallback());
}
public void initAnim(MapsActivity mapAct){
    this.mapAct = mapAct;
    show = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mapAct, R.anim.show);
    hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mapAct, R.anim.hide);
}

public void show(ParseObject area){
    if(status.equals(Status.HIDDEN)){
        startAnimation(show);
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        status = Status.SHOW;

        //hashMarker.get(marker.getId())
    }
    nameText.setText(area.getString("name"));
}
public void hide(){
    if(status.equals(Status.SHOW)){
        startAnimation(hide);
        setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        status = Status.HIDDEN;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


    if (isTarget(event) /*&& mDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(event)*/) {
        //Log.e("intercept", "intercept true");
        return true;
    } else {
        //Log.e("intercept", "intercept false");
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (isTarget(event) || isMoving()) {
        mDragHelper.processTouchEvent(event);
        //Log.e("touch", "touch true");
        return true;
    } else {
        //Log.e("touch", "touch false");
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}

private boolean isTarget(MotionEvent event) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    whitePanel.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int upperLimit = location[1] + whitePanel.getMeasuredHeight();
    int lowerLimit = location[1] - namePanel.getMeasuredHeight();
    int y = (int) event.getRawY();
    //Log.e("touch", "upper target: " + upperLimit +" & lower target: "+ lowerLimit);
    //Log.e("touch", "touch at: " + y);
    return (y > lowerLimit && y < upperLimit);
}

private class DragHelperCallback extends ViewDragHelper.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean tryCaptureView(View view, int pointerId) {
        //Log.e("capture", "Capture white is " + (view.getId() == R.id.white_pane) + " but it capture " + view.getId());
        //return (view.getId() == R.id.white_pane);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewDragStateChanged(int state) {
        if (state == mDraggingState) { // no change
            return;
        }
        if ((mDraggingState == ViewDragHelper.STATE_DRAGGING || mDraggingState == ViewDragHelper.STATE_SETTLING) &&
                state == ViewDragHelper.STATE_IDLE) {
            // the view stopped from moving.

            if (mDraggingBorder == 0) {
                onStopDraggingToClosed();
            } else if (mDraggingBorder == mVerticalRange) {
                mIsOpen = true;
            }
        }
        if (state == ViewDragHelper.STATE_DRAGGING) {
            onStartDragging();
        }
        mDraggingState = state;
        Log.e("Drag" , "State changed : " + state);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewPositionChanged(View changedView, int left, int top, int dx, int dy) {
        mDraggingBorder = top;
    }

    public int getViewVerticalDragRange(View child) {
        return mVerticalRange;
    }
    @Override
    public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
        final int topBound = getPaddingTop();
        final int bottomBound = mVerticalRange;
        Log.e("Drag" , "clamp at topBound = " + topBound + " and bottom = " + bottomBound + " and top= " + top);
        //return Math.min(Math.max(top, topBound), bottomBound);
        //status = top>0? Status.SLIDE_DOWN:Status.SLIDE_UP;
        return Math.min(top, bottomBound);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewReleased(View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) {
        final float rangeToCheck = mVerticalRange;
        Log.e("Drag" , "Released. rangeToCheck: " + rangeToCheck + " and mDraggingBorder: " + mDraggingBorder);
        if (mDraggingBorder == 0) {
            mIsOpen = false;
            return;
        }
        if (mDraggingBorder == rangeToCheck) {
            mIsOpen = true;
            return;
        }
        Log.e("Drag" , "Released. y velocity = " + yvel);
        boolean settleToOpen = false;
        if (yvel > AUTO_OPEN_SPEED_LIMIT) { // speed has priority over position
            settleToOpen = true;
            Log.e("drag" , "FUCKING OVER SPEED");
        } else if (yvel < -AUTO_OPEN_SPEED_LIMIT) {
            settleToOpen = true;
        } else if (Math.abs(mDraggingBorder )> rangeToCheck / 2) {
            settleToOpen = true;
        } else if (Math.abs(mDraggingBorder) < rangeToCheck / 2) {
            settleToOpen = false;
        }

        int settleDestY = settleToOpen ? mVerticalRange : 0;
        if(yvel > AUTO_OPEN_SPEED_LIMIT) settleDestY = 0;
        Log.e("drag" , "settle Dest Y : " + settleDestY );
        if(mDraggingBorder < 0)settleDestY = settleDestY * -1;

        if(mDragHelper.settleCapturedViewAt(0, settleDestY)) {
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(SlidePanel.this);
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    //mVerticalRange = (int) (h * 0.66);
    int inPixel = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 110, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    mVerticalRange = h - inPixel;
    //super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

private void onStopDraggingToClosed() {
    // To be implemented
    Log.e("Drag" , "On stop drag to close");
}

private void onStartDragging() {
    Log.e("Drag" , "On start drag");
}
@Override
public void computeScroll() { // needed for automatic settling.
    if (mDragHelper.continueSettling(true)) {
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
    }
}

public boolean isMoving() {
    return (mDraggingState == ViewDragHelper.STATE_DRAGGING ||
            mDraggingState == ViewDragHelper.STATE_SETTLING);
}

public boolean isOpen() {
    if(status == Status.SHOW){
        return false;
    }else{
        return mIsOpen;
    }
}
```

}